# HTTP Status 404 error when accessing http://localhost:8080/solr

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, lucene

I have been trying to setup Solr with Apache Tomcat, and I can see the localhost:8080 Tomcat page, but when i try to reach the localhost:8080/solr page i get the following message:

"HTTP Status 404 - /solr

type Status report

message /solr

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.15"

Im using the Solr 4.10.2 and has been using the following guide to install: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/lucene_solr_sql_server

I have set up apache-tomcat-8.0.15 and solr-4.10.2 both in C:\sw,

copied solr-4.10.2\example\solr to C:\sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.15

solr-4.10.2\dist\Solr 4.10.2.war to  C:\sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\webapps\Solr 4.10.2.war

also tried changing the web.xml to the following:

```
<env-entry>

   <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>

   <env-entry-value>C:\sw\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\solr</env-entry-value>

   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>

</env-entry>
```

read the stackoverflow questions regarding this, and didnt managed to resolve the issue
Thanks

Comment: try renaming `webapps\Solr 4.10.2.war` to `webapps\solr.war` and restart tomcat

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but you may try using [Heliosearch](http://heliosearch.com/heliosearch-distribution-for-solr/) which is a free distro for Solr, coming from one of Solr developers - already packaged with Tomcat.

Comment: try accessing solr/home ?

Comment: you try to restart Apache Tomcat.

Comment: tried webapps\solr.war

Comment: tried accessing solr/home, and restarted, but still didnt help

Comment: Thanks mindas, I used Heliosearch and it solved the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue,and I don't want to use Heliosearch.Did anyone found any solution?